# Increase character length of product description on category page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

This is my website

[My website click here](http://thegoodgalette.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_61)

Below is the code

```
'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0,100, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
```

I need to know how to increase the character length of product description on category page in opencart 2.3.x

I searched on the internet but didn't find any proper answer.

Comment: Please make the title a description of your question, and the body of your question an actual question. You also should include code and samples of what you're expecting.

Comment: This is the code

'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0,100, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
The description is limit to certain characters, I want to increase it to actual.

If you click on the link given in the description you will come to know.

Comment: Do you want to show all category description?

Answer (score 1):

**we can increase character length of product discription on category page in opencart 2.3**

**follow this steps**

Go to Admin panel of opencart 2.3 
- Go to Extensions -> select the theme -> Click Edit

[image]

Now you will see Product Section, in that you can see option 'List Description Limit'

[image]

Here You can increase character length of product description.

Enter how many character you want and save it.

Thank You.

Comment: I tried this but didnt worked.
Even refresh cache and cookies.

Comment: 'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['descripti‌​on'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0,100, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length'))

Comment: 0,100 is the length you have to set that what you want .

Comment: I want it to be infinite, or fit the content

Comment: you can set 0,99999 bcoz in desc you cant add more then that.